# Python csv - count number of strings in a column depending on value on another column

Tags: python, csv

I'm learning Python right now, and I came across a small challenge with the CSV files that I cannot figure out. I have a CSV file with 5 columns and 500 rows (501 with the headers of the columns) as the following example:

```
ID  X  X  X  Answer
1             Yes
2             Yes
2             Yes
3             No
3             No
4             No
2             Yes
1             No
4             Yes
3             No
4             Yes
5             No
```

1. I need to get how many of the IDs answered `Yes` at least once.
2. And how many of the IDs only answered `Yes` always.

So here I would need to get an output like:

```
number of IDs that answered Yes at least once: 3
number of IDs that always answered Yes: 1
```

- Since IDs 1, 2, and 4 have a Yes in the Answer column at least once. And IDs 3 and 5 never answered Yes.
- And ID 2 always had a Yes as an answer

This is what I tried so far...

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

with open('results.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for row in readCSV:
        data[row[4]].append(row[0])
    for k, v in data.items():
        print(k)
        #print(Counter(v))

    def get_number_of_elements(list):
        count = 0
        for element in list:
            count += 1
        return count
    print("number of IDs that answered Yes at least once: ", get_number_of_elements(Counter(v)))
```

As well this one:

```
import csv
import collections
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

with open('results.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # initializes the answer with default value as int which will be 0.
    DUT_ok = collections.defaultdict(int)

    for input in readCSV:
        answer[input[0]] += 1 if input[4] in ['Yes'] else 0

        # finally printing our dict formed.
    for key, value in answer.items():
        if value == '1':
            print(key, '-', value)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to ask here? Are you asking us If the code quality is good?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this using a dictionary of dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

with open('f00.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        d[ row['ID'] ][ row['Answer'] ] += 1

all_yes = [k for k, v in d.items() if 'No' not in v]    
print(all_yes) # prints ['2']
    
some_yes = [k for k, v in d.items() if 'Yes' in v]    
print(some_yes) # prints ['1', '2', '4']
```

To get the counts (and not the IDs):

```
all_yes = sum('No' not in v for v in d.values())
print(all_yes) # prints 1


some_yes = sum('Yes' in v for v in d.values())
print(some_yes) # prints 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to track both "yes" and "no" answers to answer your questions.

```
import csv

counts = {}
with open('results.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for input in readCSV:
        if input[0] not in counts:
            counts[input[0]] = [0,0]
        if input[4] == 'Yes':
            counts[input[0]][1] += 1
        else:
            counts[input[0]][0] += 1

print(counts)
for key, value in counts.items():
    if value[0] + value[1] == 0:
        print( key, "answered no questions" )
    if value[1]:  # some yeses
        if value[0]:  # some nos
            print( key, "answered yes at least once" )
        else:
            print( key, "always answered yes" )
```

Comment: Thank you! There would be any way in which I can show in a print the exact number of how many people always answered yes and how many at least once?

Comment: Of course there is, but you need to do that.  It is an easy change, and we can't write the whole assignment for you.